# How to avoid having 2 times | async in this situation (4.0.0)?

Tags: angular, subscription

I would like to avoid to use .subscribe() in this component.
I tried `*ngIf="user$ | async as user"` but it did not work.

**How can I make a local variable with `user$ | async` un order to use it at different places in this view?**

```html
<app-xpbar *ngIf="user$ | async"></app-xpbar>

<header class="header">

  <app-header-common
    (onSearch)="searching($event)">
  </app-header-common>

  <app-header-user
    [user]="user$ | async"
    (onLogin)="login($event)"
    (onTrial)="trial($event)">
  </app-header-user>

</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

As @yurzui pointed out, this only works if the references to the introduced variable `user` are within the `<pp-xpbar>` element where it's introduced.
Otherwise the variable won't be in scope (like in the code example below)

**Original**

In Angular4 you can use

```ts
<app-xpbar *ngIf="user$ | async; let user"></app-xpbar>

<header class="header">

  <app-header-common
    (onSearch)="searching($event)">
  </app-header-common>

  <app-header-user
    [user]="user"
    (onLogin)="login($event)"
    (onTrial)="trial($event)">
  </app-header-user>

</header>
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta0-2016-12-15
- https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/b4db73d
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13061
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13297

For the `as` syntax mentioned in the comments see

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc4-2017-03-17

Comment: Actually I also tried that but It did not work. I'll try again then.

Comment: What Angular version?

Comment: 4.0.0. But I tried `user$ | async as user` not `user$ | async; let user`.

Comment: I think `let user` has scope within `*ngIf`

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out my mistakes @yurzui I thought I checked that the `<pp-xpbar>` closes after the `<app-header-user>`. Seems like I need better glasses.

Comment: Yes it does not seem to work. Putting `{{user | json}}` next to `<app-xpbar>` does not show the result.

Comment: @Tom that's expected. I just missed that `<app-xpbar>` closes at the same line. Perhaps you can move `*ngIf` to a common parent element?

Comment: Ok so I guess my only other possibility is to query the user in the `ParentComponent` and give it to this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create structural directive like:

**ng-async.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({ selector: '[ngAsync]' })
export class NgAsync {
   constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}

   @Input()
   set ngAsync(variable: any) {
      this.vcRef.clear();
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, { $implicit: variable });
   }
}
```

Then you can use it the following way

**view.html**

```
<ng-container *ngAsync="user$ | async; let user">
  <app-xpbar *ngIf="user"></app-xpbar>

  <header class="header">

    <app-header-common
      (onSearch)="searching($event)">
    </app-header-common>

    <app-header-user
      [user]="user"
      (onLogin)="login($event)"
      (onTrial)="trial($event)">
    </app-header-user>

  </header>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Looks pretty nice. I'm going to try that. Thank you @yurzui.

Comment: The main disadvantage is destroying all elements after updating `user`

Comment: Yes you are right. I'll stick with a parent component then. But I'll keep this directive. It can be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking of pros and cons of differents propositions, I'll go with a `ParentComponent` event if it's here only for getting user stream.
Thanks everyone.